# Finding an element using specflow and selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, specflow

I am trying to find the google login button from this url

https://marketsmithindia.com/mstool/landing.jsp#/signIn

and getting this exception
NoSuchElementException

I am using Specflow, it is the most basic thing, just opening the browser, navigating the url and click the button.

Here is some code that I am using

```
_driver = new EdgeDriver();
_driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
_driver.Url = "https://marketsmithindia.com/mstool/landing.jsp#/signIn";
Thread.Sleep(3000);


//this is just clicking the Agreed button on terms and conditions dialog
var element = _driver.FindElement(by: By.XPath("//*[@id=\"msi_non_eu_popup\"]/div/div/div[3]/button"));
  if (element != null)
  {
      element.Click();
  }
Thread.Sleep(5000);
//this line throws exception NoSuchElementException
var googleButtonElement=_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='googlebtnclick']"));
```

It'll be great help if you could help or suggest something to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use GetShadowRoot method and filtering your element inside shadow root DOM context.

```
driver
     .FindElement(By.Id("userlogin"))
     .GetShadowRoot() <-- It will give you shadow root context
     .FindElement(By.Id("googlebtnclick"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The google button is under the Shadow DOM. You need to reach `shadow-root` element first in order to access the element.[image]

Use `JavasciptExecutor` to access the element using below query.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
var googleButtonElement = js.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('user-login').shadowRoot.querySelector('#googlebtnclick');");
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. But inbuild methods like GetShadowRoot() and find element help a bit better as chances of typos in script are bit less. Still many thanks. Cheers.